# how to Retrieve data from more than one entity using plugin,crm 2011

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

Hi guys how can i fetch data from more than one entity in crm 2011 using plugin. I am able to retrieve data from one entity and store it in other entity. But how can i fetch from more than one entity.

Comment: Can you share the code showing what you've tried?

Answer (score 0):

The logical way would be to do a seperate retrieve for each of the entities, if there are 2 or 3. You can use fetchxml, if there are joins and if you need a couple of related fields.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the data. If it two totally seperate records with no relationships, e.g. task and subject, they you will have to peform seperate queries

If the data is linked, e.g. contact and related tasks, then you can get them in a single query.

There a couple of a different ways to do this, [FetchXml, QueryExpression and Linq](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334607.aspx) or [OData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334279.aspx) if you are using the REST endpoint. All valid, just depends on what you are doing it and from where.